# paper-menu with multiple selections, howto deselect all

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I use `paper-menu` with multiple selections (`multi`). Everything works fine so fare, but with a deselect all method things seems more complicated.

With html

```
<paper-menu multi selected-values="{{selectedValues}}">...
```

Dart

```
@property
List<String> selectedValues = [];...
```

Things got binded, and every `iron-select`/`iron-deselect` event results in a correct update of the `selectedValues` list in dart.

With `clear('selectedValues')` the list empties and the logic behaves like no selection is done, but in Dartium the items that previous was
selected remains marked as selected.

I have also tried with the `selectedItems List` or with the foreach deselect with the `select` method to `PaperMenu`, but still not successful update
in Dartium.

Anyone with ideas how to implement this?

Comment: Select with tap from Dartium and deselect with 'select' method, seems not to work together. Wrote an issue on this https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for the issue with the select method. The menu with selected values can be replaced with a new similar element created with the Dom api. One drawback is the bindings can't be set up, so these needs to be hacked with `get` and `set` methods at the element. Otherwise this seems to work ok. The calls to the Dom api are shown below.

```
ParticipantMenu oldPm = $$('#id_filterselection') as ParticipantMenu;
ParticipantMenu newPm = document.createElement('participant-menu');

Polymer.dom(parentNode).insertBefore(newPm, oldPm);
Polymer.dom(parentNode).removeChild(oldPm);
PolymerDom.flush();
```